# Retrieve the 'Minimum order amount' for free shipping value in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to retrieve the **'Minimum order amount'** value for free shipping in the **'CartController.php'** class.

How can I get this value? Would `Mage::getStoreConfig()` do the job? But which path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the values are stored in the core_config_data table, and a search `WHERE path like '%minimum%'` should result in few enough rows for you to spot which one. Alternatively, the 'name' of the input-field in the admin area will be the path with _s in place of /s.

Comment: Thanks so much I managed to get the value thanks to your tip. I found also a good way to find the path by doing a print_r(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers')). If anybody need the Minimum order amount value for free shipping here is the path 'carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal'.

Answer (score 4):

Without VAT:

```
function getRemainingAmount() 
{
      $symbol  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
      $total   = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();    
      $minimum = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal");

      $value = $minimum - $total;

      if ($value < 0) {
           return false;    
      } else {   
           return number_format($value, 2) . $symbol;
      }
}
```